# where to find the log file in my project?

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j

I have created sample log4j class to test the configuration. I wrote the following Log4J properties file:

```
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, FILE, CONSOLE
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=X:\\logs\Log4jExample.log
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

My sample program is:

```
public class Log4jExample 
{

    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Log4jExample.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("D:\\textfile.txt");
            // use DataInputStream to read binary NOT text         
            // DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));

            String strLine;
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println (strLine);
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fe) {
            log.error("File Not Found",fe);
            log.warn("This is a warning message");
            log.trace("This message will not be logged since log level is set as DEBUG");      
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("IOEXception occured:", e);
        }
    }
}
```

I am receiving the expected output in my console but I am unable to locate my generated log file. I have set its path to `X:\\logs`. But no such log files are being created.

Please help.

Comment: Are you getting any  logs in Console ?

Comment: am getting right output in my console, the only problem is that it is not creating any log files. @Gk.

Answer (score 1):

Your path has double backslashes in some places and single backslashes in other places. Can you try again with all-single (or all-double) backslashes?
Another thing to try is to log to a local drive (C:) first, to see if the issue has to do with mapped network drives.

(Btw, the question is tagged log4j2 but you're using log4j-1.x)

Answer (score 0):

I don´t see any error in your configuration.
But in your initialitation, try this:

```
static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class)
```

Comment: Its not creating any log file in my destination.

Comment: I would use a relative path and the log should be created in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Change `X:\\logs\test.log` to `X://logs/test.log` path
Generally people tends to give relative path like `log/MutationPipeline.log`

Answer (score 0):

Is X: a mapped network drive? I remember having trouble writing to a mapped network drive from Java on Windows at some point. It could be caused by this issue: [Windows file share: why sometimes newly created files aren't visible for some period of time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159220/windows-file-share-why-sometimes-newly-created-files-arent-visible-for-some-pe/9935126#9935126)

Can you try using a local drive like `C:/temp` to verify if you can see the log files there? That would narrow it down...