# How do I force Get-ChildItem to refresh every time?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use  Get-ChildItem  to produce a list of files, which I then want to delete, and then run the script again every five minutes via Task Scheduler, i.e. a fairly basic folder-watch task.

However it seems that the list of files is getting cached, so that newly created files are not 'seen' by the script...

```
Get-ChildItem –Path "\\server\share$\my\path" | where {($_ -like "_minidump_default_pid*.dmp")} | Remove-Item -Force | Out-File D:\MiniDump_Delete_Output.txt –Append
```

I then write a single char to the output file, so I can see that the task runs as expected.

Comment: has nothing to do with powershell, check the SMB server settings - u are right there is a cache, settings depend on OS version

Comment: The `| Out-File` part is redundant (`Remove-Item` doesn't output anything), and you probably want to be specific about which property you're testing (eg. `Where-Object { $_.Name -like "_minidump_default_pid*.dmp"}`) - but other than that your code looks fine. Did you inspect the task scheduler history to verify the script actually ran successfully the second time?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen  Yes, the task definitely runs - I write a char/line to that same output file every run, and that shows up.
This was meant to be a two-minute clone of someone else's script - am now doubting whether the original works as intended!

Comment: @Toni  If I run a cmd prompt, or run the command via the PS editor, then it shows the new files. The sched task DID remove my first test file, but none that I added afterwards.

Comment: "Remove-Item doesn't output anything" - yes it does, with the "-WhatIf" option, which I used at first.

Comment: `-WhatIf` doesn't write to the success stream, as Mathias mentioned, `Out-File` isn't needed since `Remove-Item` doesn't produce anything as it consumes the objects beforehand.

Comment: May be this can help :  https://stackoverflow.com/a/9935126